# Aligning equal signs such that the line is already aligned

Tags: align

I have an `align` question. Essentially the following code:

```
\begin{align} 
    \nonumber & \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_1)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_2)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) \\ 
    \nonumber & \cdots + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_k)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  = 1 \\ 
    \nonumber &  \sum_{i=1}^k \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)  = \exp(\mu+1) \\  
              &  \exp(-\mu-1)  = \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k} \exp\left(-\displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T} \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)}  
\end{align}
```

Produces the following:

[image: align1]

However I would like to have the equal signs in line 2, 3 and 4 all aligned, how can I do this? (Line 2 is a continuation of line 1).

Comment: Use the `&` right before the `=` to get the `=` aligned. However, how do you want the first line to be aligned?

Comment: I would like the first line and second line to stay as they are, then align the equal signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_1)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) & + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_2)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) \\
  \cdots + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_k)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  & = 1 \\
   \sum_{i=1}^k \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right) & = \exp(\mu+1) \\
            \exp(-\mu-1) & = \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k} \exp\left(-\displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T} \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{alignat}{6}
\mathrlap{\exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_1)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_2)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)} \nonumber\\
&&\dots + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_k)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  & = 1 \nonumber\\
&&\sum_{i=1}^k \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right) & = \exp(\mu+1) \nonumber\\
&&\exp(-\mu-1) & = \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k} \exp\left(-\displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T} \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)}
\end{alignat}

\begin{multline}
\exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_1)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_2)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) \\
\begin{aligned}
  \cdots + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_k)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  & = 1 \\
   \sum_{i=1}^k \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right) & = \exp(\mu+1) \\
            \exp(-\mu-1) & = \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k} \exp\left(-\displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T} \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)}
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

this might satisfy your request:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_1)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_2)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) \\
\begin{aligned}
 \cdots + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_k)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  &= 1 \\
 \sum_{i=1}^k \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)  &= \exp(\mu+1) \\
 \exp(-\mu-1)  &= \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k} \exp\left(-\displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T} \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)}
\end{aligned}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_1)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_2)\right)\exp(-\mu-1) \notag\\
\begin{aligned}
 \cdots + \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t f_t(x_k)\right)\exp(-\mu-1)  &= 1 \\
 \sum_{i=1}^k \exp\left(-\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)  &= \exp(\mu+1) \\
 \exp(-\mu-1)  &= \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^k} \exp\left(-\displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T} \lambda_t f_t(x_i) \right)}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```